# How do you express that your children to sit down to study by themselves without your urge?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

This is one of the problems that all parents face. That is your children don't sit down to study by themselves because they think they must do it. But most children only sit down to study when their parents urged or forced them to do it.

In other words, the children are internally driven to study without external pressure.

Do we have a verb or any word that is used to express that your children to sit down to study by themselves without your urge?

For example, "**my children study with self-awareness**"

or "**my children study on their own initiative**"

or "**my children are self-motivated in studying**"

Comment: @Lambie [Urge **is** a noun](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/urge). However, the usage in the title is unidiomatic.

Comment: There can be very many nuances of this! Even if the children study without you telling them to, do they study because they can anticipate that you'd be disappointed if they didn't? Or do they study because they want to get good grades at the next school test? Or do they study because they want to get into a prestigious school next year? Or do they study because they actually want to learn things? Etc etc

Comment: @Flater Yes, an oversight. The urge to do x. Yes, unidiomatic in the title. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying this to a teacher, doctor, social worker, or other professional? Or to another parent in an informal chat? The terms used could be very different.

Answer (score 8):

There are no magic words.  You just make a sentence using the normal meaning of words.

"Self-awareness" doesn't mean "without external urging" so that expression doesn't work.  The others are correct, but not the only sentences that you could construct.

Comment: I thought of: My children are self-motivated to study. +1 for the self-awareness thing.

Comment: @Lambie Yours seems to be the most natural response here

Answer (score 8):

- My children study [of their own accord](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of-ones-own-accord).
- My children study [of their own volition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of-ones-own-volition).
- My children study [of their own free will](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of-your-own-free-will).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "*My children study of their own free will*" sounds more friendly

Comment: I found the following resource clarifying "of [their/your] own free will" https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of-your-own-free-will

Comment: +1.  All of these are good, but “…of their own accord” sounds most natural to me in everyday contexts — the other two sound slightly more formal or academic.

Comment: My children are self-motivated to study. Free will is a bit strong here.

Answer (score 5):

"Happily" is often used to indicate that someone does something willingly. While you could pedantically point out that doing something happily can still mean only doing it when instructed (but without protest), casual speech is not bound to such precise interpretations.

If you were to say:

> My children happily study on their own.

I would interpret that they engage in the activity without needing to be told to do so against their will, which is the point I think you're trying to get across in this question.

---

This is supported by [the dictionary definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/happily), which includes an expression of willingness (as opposed to happiness):

> **happily** - *adverb*
> (definition B2) willingly
> *I'd happily offer to help him if I thought it would make any difference.*

[A second link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/happily) has a better example (in my opinion):

> I'd happily drive you to the airport.

This is an expression of willingness. It does not directly express the emotion experienced during the drive.

Although to be fair the reason for this dual meaning does rely on an implication that the person is willing to do so because doing so would make them happy.

Comment: Interestingly, the position of "happily" in the sentence tends to change who is happy about it: "Happily, my children study on their own" vs. "My children happily study on their own"

Comment: I think that goes beyond the mark.  A child could study without prompting because they feel it is necessary or their duty without actually being happy about it.

Comment: @nasch You're bringing it down to a level of granularity and ambiguity that is not given an ironclad defense in informal speech. Being able to think of an edge case does not invalidate the idiomatic nature of a certain turn of phrase. Your reply only makes sense if you suppose that correct answers or idiomatic phrasings should never contain any ambiguity, which is simply unrealistic in pretty much every language (other than legalese).

Comment: @Stef Your example leaves it ambiguous rather than definitely shifting the focus. As evidenced by changing the adverb to "quietly" which would clearly still refer to the children.

Comment: @Flater I disagree.  I think if someone uses the word "happily" they usually mean "happily", not "independently" or "without prompting".  It's not an edge case, it's just the literal meaning of the word.  I think you're being overly defensive of your answer.

Comment: @nasch: It seems you are disagreeing with the dictionary itself. [Happily](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/happily) has 
 more than one definition, the second being closer in meaning to "willingly" than "in a happy state". [Second link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/happily) example "I'll **happily** drive you to the airport" very much expresses a willingness rather than the overarching emotion that is experienced during said drive.

Answer (score 1):

1. My children have developed independent study habit.
2. My children study by their own will.

Comment: I've not heard "by their own will" before. i like the "developed _an_ independent study habit"

Comment: of their own free will, yes. independent study habits OR as Sandra says.

Answer (score 1):

1. My children initiate studying without being prompted.

is exactly the message expressed in the title, correcting for the awkward word choice.

2. My children take the initiative to study.

is very similar to one of the options offered in the question, but emphasizes the initiative more.

Answer (score 1):

I think you hit the nail on the head with "self-motivated". I would say this exactly and idiomatically expresses what you are getting at.

"My children are self-motivated to study."

"My children are self-motivated when it comes to studying."

"My children study without my needing to pressure them; they are self-motivated."

Answer (score 1):

**My children are self-motivated to study.**

Free will is a bit strong here.

If you do not urge them to study, they are self-motivated.

Answer (score 0):

The word that immediately comes to my mind is **studious**.  While studious has several meanings, the most commonly used meaning is to describe someone who enjoys studying.

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/studious)

> A studious person enjoys studying or spends a lot of time studying:

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/studious)

> 1. assiduous (showing great care, attention to detail, and effort) in the pursuit of learning
> 2. a. of, relating to, or concerned with study
>    b. favorable to study,
> 3. a. diligent or earnest in intent
>    b. marked by or suggesting purposefulness or diligence
>    c. deliberately or consciously planned

So you could just say:
**My children are studious.**